# oracle - Select from tables into object variable

Tags: sql, oracle, object, plsql, user-defined-types

Say I have this Object type:

```
create or replace
TYPE                   "InvestorInfoObject" AS OBJECT 
  ( 
  "InvestorAccount" Varchar2(15 Char), 
  "InvestorSeqNo" NUMBER(15,0), 
  "FirstName" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) , 
   );
```

I need a function to select some values from different tables and return an "InvestorInfoObject". something like this:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION          "GetInvestorInfo" 
(
  Par_InvestorAccount "Pos"."InvestorAccount"%Type
)
Return "InvestorInfoObject" As 
  investorObj "InvestorInfoObject";
Begin


    Select 
      "InvestorInfoObject"(InvAccounts."InvestorAccount",InvAccounts."InvestorSeqNo",Individuals."FirstName") 
      into investorObj 
      From "InvestorAccounts" InvAccounts 
      Inner Join "Individuals" Individuals 
          On InvAccounts."InvestorSeqNo"=Individuals."Seq"
      Where "InvestorAccount"=Par_Investoraccount;


  RETURN Investorobj;
END "GetInvestorInfo";
```

but this results in Error "Error(17,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored". what is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: please, please don't use case-sensitive double-quoted identifiers :)

Comment: @beherenow, don't be so harsh on double-quoted identifiers. I got rid of them, still getting error. I assume I there is some trouble with the syntax.

Comment: Turns out i have been misplacing parenthesis! PL/SQL compiler messages reminds of old time coding in assembly!

Comment: @sjjafari I never said your issue was due to identifiers

Comment: The reason do not use case-sensitive identifiers has nothing to do with errors but with convenience. It's a lot easier to _not_ use them... there's no need to do so and you're a lot less likely to make mistakes.

Comment: You have to use case-sensitive double-quoted identifiers in case you like to make output to XML, e.g. `SELECT XMLTYPE("InvestorInfoObject"(...`. Otherwise all elements in your XML get uppder-case which is quite uncommon.

Comment: I've never seen this syntax to return objects from functions.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about returning more then one value that can be done using collection this

can be used

declare

type student_mark is varray(10) of integer;

x student_mark;

function double_marks(x student_mark) return

student_mark is

y student_mark;

begin

y := x;

for i in 1..x.count loop

y(i) := 2*y(i);

end loop;

return y;

end;

begin

x := student_mark(156, 206, 360);

dbms_output.put_line(double_marks(x)(1));

dbms_output.put_line(double_marks(x)(2));

dbms_output.put_line(double_marks(x)(3));

end;

here you can use object also instead of varray . i will get back to you once i execute the

code provided by you